# Bad version number in .class file

Tags: maven, jetty, java-5, unsupported-class-version

I am trying to deploy a webapp in my local Jetty with Maven.

My Java -version in command line is

```
java version "1.5.0_22"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_22-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_22-b03, mixed mode, sharing)
```

In Eclipse, my project's JDK Compliance is set to 'Use Compliance  from execution Environment J2SE-1.5 on the Build path', which is JDK1.5.0_22 as well.

No matter where I try to run it from, either command line with `mvn jetty:run` or Eclipse configuring a VM like this

[image]

I get the same errors.

```
    Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 4000
        [INFO] Scanning for projects...
        [WARNING] 
        [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.ow2.frascati.examples:frascati-gae:war:1.5-SNAPSHOT
        [WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar -> version 2.1.13 vs 2.1.12 @ line 103, column 17
        [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ org.ow2.frascati.examples:parent:1.5-SNAPSHOT, C:\WorkSpace\FrascatiTrunk\examples\pom.xml, line 93, column 15
        [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin:maven-replacer-plugin is missing. @ org.ow2.frascati.examples:frascati-in-the-cloud:1.5-SNAPSHOT, C:\WorkSpace\FrascatiTrunk\examples\frascati-in-the-cloud\pom.xml, line 462, column 15
        [WARNING] 
        [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
        [WARNING] 
        [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
        [WARNING] 
        [INFO]                                                                         
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] Building OW2 FraSCAti in Google App Engine 1.5-SNAPSHOT
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] >>> maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.26:run (default-cli) @ frascati-gae >>>
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ frascati-gae ---
        [debug] execute contextualize
        [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
        [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\WorkSpace\FrascatiTrunk\examples\frascati-in-the-cloud\Google App Engine\src\main\resources
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ frascati-gae ---
        [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ frascati-gae ---
        [debug] execute contextualize
        [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
        [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\WorkSpace\FrascatiTrunk\examples\frascati-in-the-cloud\Google App Engine\src\test\resources
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ frascati-gae ---
        [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] <<< maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.26:run (default-cli) @ frascati-gae <<<
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] --- maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.26:run (default-cli) @ frascati-gae ---
        [INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: OW2 FraSCAti in Google App Engine
        [INFO] Webapp source directory = C:\WorkSpace\FrascatiTrunk\examples\frascati-in-the-cloud\Google App Engine\target\webapp
        [INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
        [INFO] Classes = C:\WorkSpace\FrascatiTrunk\examples\frascati-in-the-cloud\Google App Engine\target\classes
        2012-10-04 10:25:26.688:INFO::Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
        [INFO] Context path = /frascati-gae
        [INFO] Tmp directory =  determined at runtime
        [INFO] Web defaults = org/mortbay/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
        [INFO] Web overrides =  none
        [INFO] web.xml file = C:\WorkSpace\FrascatiTrunk\examples\frascati-in-the-cloud\Google App Engine\target\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml
        [INFO] Webapp directory = C:\WorkSpace\FrascatiTrunk\examples\frascati-in-the-cloud\Google App Engine\target\webapp
        [INFO] Starting jetty 6.1.26 ...
        2012-10-04 10:25:26.770:INFO::jetty-6.1.26
        2012-10-04 10:25:27.070:WARN::Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext@f553e3{/frascati-gae,C:\WorkSpace\FrascatiTrunk\examples\frascati-in-the-cloud\Google App Engine\target\webapp}
        java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6MavenConfiguration.parseAnnotations(Jetty6MavenConfiguration.java:142)

.
.
.

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
            at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)

.
.
.

        [INFO] Started Jetty Server
        2012-10-04 10:25:27.156:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
        [INFO] Starting scanner at interval of 10 seconds.
```

I am confused with the

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
```

since I've been getting this ever since I changed to J2SE-1.5, because the project requirements specified so.

I even deleted my whole m2repo and had Maven redownloading it all.

I am a bit lost with this mix of errors. Can anyone throw any light on this?

**EDIT:**

If I change my Java version to JDK-1.6 it works "fine" (different unrelated errors).

But why? Shouldn't it work if the project requirements are Java 1.5?
Besides, Shouldn't all the repositories that Maven downloaded be compatible with 1.5 since that's what they where compiled with before deploying?

**EDIT 2:** (regarding @Kal's comment)

My project is a subproject example of a main Trunk. To compile it I run Maven on the POM of my example project which depends on previous POMs. In its parent POM, in the examples directory, there is:

```
 <!-- Compile with Java 1.5 -->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.5</source>
            <target>1.5</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

**EDIT 3:**

Here is my dependency.tree:

```
[INFO] org.ow2.frascati.examples:frascati-gae:war:1.5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.12:runtime (scope not updated to co
mpile)
[INFO] +- org.ow2.frascati.examples:fibonacci:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-binding-rest:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-metamodel-frascati:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:co
mpile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.ow2.frascati.model:frascati-model:jar:2.0.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.ow2.frascati.model:sca-model:jar:2.0.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        +- org.eclipse.emf:ecore:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        |  \- org.eclipse.core:runtime:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        |     \- org.eclipse.equinox:common:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        +- org.eclipse.emf.ecore:xmi:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        \- org.eclipse.emf:common:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-binding-factory:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:compi
le
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.fractal.bf.connectors:fractal-bf-connectors-common:ja
r:0.10-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.ow2.fractal.bf:fractal-bf-core:jar:0.10-SNAPSHOT:compi
le
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.objectweb.fractal.fractaladl:fractal-adl:jar:2.3.1:compil
e
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.objectweb.fractal.fractaladl:ast-core:jar:2.3.1:compil
e
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- dtdparser:dtdparser:jar:1.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.objectweb.fractal.fractaladl:task-framework:jar:2.3.1:
compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.objectweb.fractal.fractaladl:task-deployment:jar:2.3.1
:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.objectweb.fractal:fractal-util:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.ow2.fractal.bf.connectors:fractal-bf-connectors-rest-cxf:jar
:0.10-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:jar:2.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:2.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-binding-ws:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.ow2.fractal.bf.connectors:fractal-bf-connectors-soap-cxf:jar
:0.10-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:2.5.4:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:2.5.4:compile
[INFO] |        |     \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:2.5.4:compil
e
[INFO] |        +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-aegis:jar:2.5.4:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:2.5.4:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:2.5.4:compile
[INFO] |        \- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.ow2.frascati.examples:isbntest:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-interface-wsdl:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics:jar:0.5.0:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-runtime:jar:0.5.0:compil
e
[INFO] |        \- org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-tools:jar:0.5.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.ow2.frascati.examples:ohloh-proxy-standalone:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:comp
ile
[INFO] +- org.ow2.frascati.examples:verifymail:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.ow2.frascati.examples:weather:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.ow2.frascati.examples:weather-mock:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-servlet-cxf:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-assembly-factory:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:compile

[INFO] |  |  +- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-sca-parser:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-util:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.frascati.tinfi:frascati-tinfi-membranes-oo:jar:1.4.4:
compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.ow2.frascati.tinfi:frascati-tinfi-runtime:jar:1.4.4:co
mpile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.objectweb.fractal.juliac:juliac-runtime:jar:2.4:com
pile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.ow2.frascati.tinfi:frascati-tinfi-runtime-api:jar:1
.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.oasis-open.sca.j:sca-caa-apis:jar:1.1-CD04:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.eclipse.stp.sca.osoa.java:osoa-java-api:jar:2.0.1.2
:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- org.objectweb.fractal.fraclet.java:fraclet-annotations:
jar:3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.ow2.frascati.model:sca-model-introspection:jar:2.0.1.3:co
mpile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-component-factory-tinfi-oo:jar:1.5-SNA
PSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-component-factory:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:
compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:2.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-common:jar:2.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty:jar:2.5.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:7.4.5.v20110725:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec:jar:1.1.2:co
mpile
[INFO] +- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-web-explorer:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-binding-http:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-metamodel-tuscany:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:com
pile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.ow2.frascati.model:tuscany-model:jar:2.0.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-web-explorer-bootstrap:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:c
ompile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-implementation-velocity:jar:1.5-SNAPSH
OT:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-metamodel-web:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:comp
ile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-implementation-fractal:jar:1.5-SNAPSHO
T:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.objectweb.fractal.julia:julia-asm:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.objectweb.fractal.julia:julia-mixins:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-component-factory-julia:jar:1.5-SNAPSH
OT:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.objectweb.fractal.julia:julia-runtime:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-introspection-impl:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:compi
le
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-bootstrap-jdt-rest:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:co
mpile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-binding-jsonrpc:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:compi
le
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.ow2.fractal.bf.connectors:fractal-bf-connectors-json-rpc:
jar:0.10-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ow2.frascati.upnp:frascati-binding-upnp:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:com
pile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.frascati.upnp:frascati-metamodel-upnp:jar:1.5-SNAPSHO
T:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.fractal.bf.connectors:fractal-bf-connectors-upnp:jar:
0.10-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.fractal.bf.binjiu.runtime:controlpoint:jar:0.2-SNA
PSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.fractal.bf.binjiu.description:model:jar:0.2-SNA
PSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.cybergarage.cyberlink:upnp-stack:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |     \- net.sf.kxml:kxml2:jar:2.1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.fractal.bf.binjiu.runtime:device:jar:0.2-SNAPSHOT:
compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.ow2.fractal.bf.binjiu.description:upnp2java:jar:0.2
-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.ow2.fractal.bf.binjiu.description:java2upnp:jar:0.2-SN
APSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ow2.frascati.gcs:frascati-binding-jgroups:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:c
ompile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.frascati.gcs:frascati-metamodel-gcs:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:
compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jgroups:jgroups:jar:2.12.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-binding-jms:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-util-xml:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.objectweb.joram:joram-client-jms:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:
compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.objectweb.joram:joram-shared:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.objectweb.joram:jcup:jar:5.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- soap:soap:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.objectweb.joram:jndi-client:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.objectweb.joram:jndi-shared:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- org.objectweb.joram:a3-common:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |        +- org.ow2.jonas.osgi:monolog:jar:5.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |        \- org.osgi:org.osgi:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.objectweb.joram:jndi-server:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.objectweb.joram:a3-rt:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.objectweb.joram:joram-mom-core:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ow2.frascati.native:frascati-binding-jna:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:co
mpile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.frascati.native:frascati-metamodel-native:jar:1.5-SNA
PSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:3.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-binding-rmi:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.ow2.fractal.bf.connectors:fractal-bf-connectors-rmi:jar:0
.10-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-introspection-api:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:com
pile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.frascati.model:osoa-java-api:jar:2.0.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.objectweb.fractal:fractal-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-common-utilities:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.1.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |        \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided (scope not updated to compi
le)
[INFO] +- org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:jar:2.5-20081211:provided (scope not upd
ated to compile)
[INFO] +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:provided (scope not u
pdated to compile)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:provided

[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:runtime
[INFO] +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.16:provided (scope not updated to comp
ile)
[INFO] |  \- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.16:provided
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:7.4.5.v20110725:runtime (scope not up
dated to compile)
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:7.4.5.v20110725:provided (sco
pe not updated to compile)
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:7.4.5.v20110725:provided (scope not u
pdated to compile)
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:7.4.5.v20110725:provided
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:7.4.5.v20110725:provided (scope n
ot updated to compile)
[INFO] +- org.objectweb.monolog:monolog-api:jar:1.8:provided (scope not updated
to compile)
[INFO] +- org.objectweb.monolog:monolog:jar:1.8:provided (scope not updated to c
ompile)
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.1.13:provided (scope not updated to ru
ntime)
[INFO] +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec:jar:1.7.1:provide
d (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] +- org.jabsorb:jabsorb:jar:1.3.1:provided (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.0:provided (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.5.0:provided (scope not updated to compile
)
[INFO] +- org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:runtime:jar:0.4.1.5:provided (scope not update
d to compile)
[INFO] +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:provided (scope not upda
ted to compile)
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.3:provided (scope not updated
to compile)
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-core:jar:2.4.2:provided (scope not upd
ated to compile)
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-validator:jar:2.4.2:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-common:jar:2.4.2:runtime
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-frontend-jaxws:jar:2.4.2:provided (sco
pe not updated to compile)
[INFO] |  \- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-databinding-jaxb:jar:2.4.2:provided (s
cope not updated to compile)
[INFO] +- org.eclipse:osgi:jar:3.4.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.core:jobs:jar:3.4.0:provided
[INFO] +- asm:asm-util:jar:3.1:provided (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] |  \- asm:asm-tree:jar:3.1:provided
[INFO] +- asm:asm-analysis:jar:3.1:provided (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:provided (scope not updated to run
time)
[INFO] +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:provided (scope not updated to com
pile)
[INFO] +- javax.script:script-api:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1:provided (scope not updated to runtime
)
[INFO] +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:provided (scope not updated to com
pile)
[INFO] +- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-runtime-factory:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:provided (s
cope not updated to compile)
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-component-factory-juliac-jdt:jar:1.5-SNAP
SHOT:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-component-factory-juliac:jar:1.5-SNAPS
HOT:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.objectweb.fractal.juliac:juliac-core:jar:2.4.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:r07:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objectweb.fractal.juliac:juliac-jdt:jar:2.4.3:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- org.eclipse.jdt:core:jar:3.3.0.771:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-component-factory-juliac-tinfi-oo:jar:1.5
-SNAPSHOT:provided
[INFO] |     \- org.ow2.frascati.tinfi:frascati-tinfi-oo:jar:1.4.4:provided
[INFO] |        +- org.objectweb.fractal.juliac:juliac-oo:jar:2.4:provided
[INFO] |        \- org.ow2.frascati.tinfi:frascati-tinfi-mixins:jar:1.4.4:provid
ed
[INFO] \- org.ow2.frascati:frascati-explorer-api:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT:provided
[INFO]    +- org.objectweb.fractal.fractalexplorer:fractal-explorer:jar:1.1.4:pr
ovided
[INFO]    |  +- org.objectweb.util.explorer:explorer:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.objectweb.apollon:apollon-runtime:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO]    |  |     +- org.objectweb.util.misc:ow-misc:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO]    |  |     \- org.objectweb.util:commandline:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO]    |  +- org.objectweb.util.explorer.plugins:explorer-reflector-plugin:ja
r:1.0:provided
[INFO]    |  \- jgraph:jgraph:jar:fractal:provided
[INFO]    \- org.swinglabs:swing-layout:jar:1.0.3:provided
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 40.787s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Oct 04 12:22:34 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/112M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Looking at the stack trace it suggests that the problem occurs while loading classes from your webapp. It could be your code or it could be some other library in your application that is culprit, and I believe there is no easy way to find which one is that.

Comment: If you are building with Maven, have you explicitly configured the maven-compiler-plugin? As of Maven 3 I believe default level of source compatibility is 5 but it could well be 6.

Comment: @Kal, I thought Maven used the compiler of the JDK I had set as default. I haven't done that. Where do I do it?

Comment: @eskalera http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html. I would also run it in an environment where there is no JDK 6 installed, just to be sure. This can fix this but it also might not, if you already reference binary libraries that expect java 1.6, then you might need to resolve those case-by-case.

Comment: @eskalera more precisely, Maven should honor JAVA_HOME env variable and use the JDK pointed by it. I verified that default source compatibility is 1.5 as of latest maven-compiler-plugin, which means that even if you are using 1.6 to compile you should be okay. I think it could be some dependency libraries that are bringing in classes compiled with 1.6 check `mvn dependency:tree` to see any hints.

Comment: so according to eis' comment and my EDIT 2 and to Kal's comment I shouldn't worry about Maven compatibility. I'll inspect dependency:tree. Thx, I didnt' know this command.

Comment: @Kal, I've added my dependecy:tree in EDIT 3.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm suppossed to look for in it.

Comment: @eskalera as I mentioned, it is going to be very difficult to track down if the culprit is some (transitive) dependency. I do not know if we can somehow debug the class loader and check which class caused this problem.

Comment: Thx @Kal, I ended up downloading an image for VirtualBox of the whole platform with the source, Eclipse, Maven, Jetty... thanks for your help and knowledge. even though I couldn't fix it I indeed learned something :)